# How to download latest file or recently added file from Aws S3 using PHP. (Yii2)

Tags: php, amazon-s3, yii2

I have a non-versioned S3 bucket (VersionId is null for all files), files have different names.
My current code is:

```
        $path = $this->key.'/primary/pdfs/'.$id.'/';

        $result = $this->s3->listObjects(['Bucket' => $this->bucket,"Prefix" => $path])->toArray();
       //get the last object from s3
        $object = end($result['Contents']);
        $key = $object['Key'];
        $file = $this->s3->getObject([
            'Bucket' => $this->bucket,
            'Key' => $key
        ]);
       //download the file
        header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
        echo $file['Body'];
```

The above is incorrect as it is giving the end file which is not the latest file.
Do I  need to use the below api call ? if so, how to use it ?

```
        $result = $this->s3->listObjectVersions(['Bucket' => $this->bucket,"Prefix" => $path])->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the VersionId of all files is null, there should be only one version of the files in the bucket

Comment: The 'Body' property in the 'GetObject' result set is a stream object, you can use $file ['Body']-> getContents () to get the content of the file

Comment: Yes, there will be only one version of files, I can get the content of the file, but first i have to get correct file I guess

Comment: Don't you know the key of the file？